# Open Select list from overriden input - material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
  <Select
    value={text}
    onChange={handleChange}
    label={formatMessage(messages.dateFilter)}
    input={
      <Box display="flex" className={classes.input}>
        <Calendar />
        <Typography variant="caption">{text}</Typography>
      </Box>
    }
  >
    {items.map(entity => {
      return (
        <MenuItem value={entity.text}>
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Typography variant="caption">{entity.text}</Typography>
            {text === entity.text && <CheckMark />}
          </Box>
        </MenuItem>
      )
    })}
  </Select>
```

As you can see I try to override input property in `Select` list , but now when I click on this field it doesn't open select list popup. I've also tried to use `open` property (set it to true), but it also doesn't work. How can I solve it ?

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.5.2",
```

[image: Edit competent-greider-nsyvz]

Comment: please, add a sandbox, or another type of demo. It will be more helpful to advice you.

Comment: Yes, a reproducible sandbox would be help a lot in figuring out what's wrong. I'm guessing you might need to forward a `ref` to your custom input component.

Comment: @RobertCooper, I've tried to create const ref = useRef() -> ref={ref} , but in ref.current there is no object , there is some dom element , and I didn't get what shoul I do with this , how can use it and which event should I call to open select list

Comment: @AskMen  I've attached sandbox button

Comment: @RobertCooper  I've attached sandbox button